# How to split a MULTIPLE integers values column in linq

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net, linq

I have to filter the records based on a column(datatype: string) integers values using LINQ for eg., IDs: 3,34,35,36,98,43.

Also i tried with the split in linq, this is my scenario

```
Banners = Banners.Where(Function(x) Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(x.IDs) AndAlso x.[IDs].Split(New Char() {","c}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Select(Function(a) Convert.ToInt32(a)).Contains(3))
```

my Scenario when doing the split on the IDs it shows a error

Failure: Execution of 'System.Linq.Enumerable:Contains(IEnumerable`1,Int32)' on the database server side currently not implemented.

How to filter the record based on the column IDs integer value using linq?

Comment: why not use regex.matches?

Answer (score 0):

Replace the .Contains with .Where(x=>x==3).FirstOrDefault() and check for non null.

Personally if that is your data structure I would consider redesigning the db. If that doesn't happen, don't bother with  converting to int. Just search for strings.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `Split` in LINQ to SQL but you can use `String.Contains` so translate the `Split`/`Contains` into `String.Contains`:

```
Banners = Banners.Where(Function(x) Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(x.IDs) AndAlso (","+x.[IDs]+",").Contains(","+"3"+","))
```

Answer (score -1):

I was not sure about your Banner Class
but I tried with below logic, and it just worked fine

```
Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        Dim Banners = New List(Of Banner)

        Banners = Banners.Where(Function(x) Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(x.IDs) AndAlso x.[IDs].Split(",").Select(Function(a) Convert.ToInt32(a)).Contains(3)).ToList()
    End Sub

End Module

Class Banner
    Private _IDs As String

    Public Property IDs() As String
        Get
            Return "3,34,35,36,98,43"
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            _IDs = value
        End Set
    End Property

End Class
```

Only Change I have is I have added ToList() at the end of Statement while assigning to Banners object

Comment: It will be helpful, If also get to know the reason for down vote. Its Just black box :P

Comment: I got this error
Execution of 'System.Linq.Enumerable:Contains(IEnumerable`1,Int32)' on the database server side currently not implemented.

Comment: Could you please Post your Banners collection details?

Comment: LINQ to Objects and LINQ to SQL are entirely different things.

Comment: It's just a contains integers with comma separation and it's datatype is string